# Where to put menu when using angular-snap?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using snap.js with AngularJS using the angular-snap.js directive. 
https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js

I'm also using Andy Joslin's angular-mobile-nav.

I'm wondering where I should store the code for the menu:

```
<snap-drawer>
    <p>I'm a drawer! Where do I go in the angular code?</p>
</snap-drawer>
```

Because this isn't a unique page within the angular-mobile-nav, I'm currently putting the  on every page and just using a directive that contains all my menu code/html.

Seems like this could be inefficient as it is loading a new directive on each page, right? Any idea on how to do this better?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using `snap.js` but some self-written sidebar-directive. I've put the HTML for it in the index.html file (`<div id="sidebar" mobile-sidebar></div>`). I get the sidebar data from current scope by using `$route.current.locals.$scope`. And by using `ng-repeat` I can display the sidebar content (a list).
I don't know if that works, but you could try to create a directive around `snap.js` (directive inception :P ).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried putting my sidebar in the index, but it didn't play well when wrapped around <mobile-nav> as the transition animations just didn't look smooth because my menu was outside the <mobile-nav> directive where all the animation happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I've done (I also use `angular-mobile-nav` and `angular-snap.js`).

This is my HTML Code

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div snap-drawer>
        <ul class="list">
            <li ng-repeat="item in sidebar.items" ng-i18next="{{item.name}}" ng-tap="snapper.close();go(item.link)"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="container" snap-content snap-options="snapOpts">
        <div mobile-view=""></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

*please note that `go()` is the function to change the page and that I'm using `ng-i18next` to translate my items. Also `ng-tap` is a directive which listens for touch events instead of mouse events. With Angular >1.1.5 there's a mobile module, so my `ng-tap` directive won't be needed anymore.*

And by using `$rootScope` I can put items in the sidebar:

```
$rootScope.sidebar = {
    items: [
        {
            name: 'item_one',
            link: 'page_one'
        },
        ...
    ]
};
```

So if you want to change the items in the sidebar, simply override `$rootScope.sidebar` (not `$scope.sidebar`) in your controller ;)

If you don't like two animations happen at the same time, you could write a function, which waits for the sidebar to close and then change the page. It could look like this:

```
$rootScope.waitThenGoTo = function (page, time) {
    time = time || 200;
    $timeout(function () {
        $navigate.go(page);
    }, time);
};
```

If you have still question, please comment. I'll try to update this answer as soon as possible.

Comment: This works, but I just couldn't get the animation to look smooth. A bit choppy as it closes the snap menu first, then slides to the next page. I need to make a decision on whether I want a smoother experience at the cost of including the HTML menu on every "page". If you have ideas on how to make the transition very smooth, please let me know. Either way, really appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look that smooth. :/ You could try to change the code, so when the sidebar closes, the content is still 'glued' to the border of the sidebar. This means, that the animations have to be synchronized, which is, well, not that easy. You could also try to change the page and then close the sidebar. I haven't tried that, but I'll let you know if I find a solution. ;)